# json_decode returning undefined/null when using etsy API

Tags: php, json, api, etsy

I'm creating a website that uses the etsy api to display shop info. I'm trying to access the individual values of the retruned json string. To do this I need to turn the returned string into an object. The only way I can see to do this is `json_decode($response_body);`, but I can't seem to get this to work. When I use the function it returns undefined/NULL when I try to get it's type. The returned string looks about like this: `{"count":3,"results":[{"listing_id":252525252,"state":"active","user_id":1111111,"category_id":1234567,"title":"Title of product","description":"This is a description"}`. Is there something I am doing completely wrong? Here is the code i'm using:

```
$url = "https://api.etsy.com/v2/shops/shopname/listings/active?api_key=".$apikey;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response_body = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if (intval($status) != 200) throw new Exception("HTTP $status\n$response_body");
$reponse_fixed = json_decode($response_body);
echo $response_fixed;
```

Comment: Is that the whole JSON string, or just a fragment? Because as a fragment, it is not valid JSON - at the least, it is missing a closing `]`

Comment: Post the output from `var_dump($response_body)` (copied from the page source so that whitespace is preserved)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yea I'm sorry that's not valid. I just tried to type it out by hand. The Json that is returned seems to be valid, though

Comment: If it is valid (can be validated with something like jsonlint.com) then json_decode() should work. Post it please, and we can take a look. You can check the output from `json_last_error_msg()`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski when I try echo var_dump($response_body) it does nothing. I'm assuming it's just returning undefined

Comment: No `echo`, just `var_dump($response_body)` - otherwise, it will try to echo a null return value since `var_dump()` writes output rather than return a string.

Comment: @McMatt Can you dump out the $response_body before and after use json_decode to me?

Comment: @duongkhang both are the same. It doesn't turn into an object or anythin

Comment: @McMatt Can you dump it out on line: $response_body = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: @duongkhang just echo it again? Still a Json string

Comment: @McMatt  Please give me that Json String I will check it out!

Comment: @duongkhang https://pastebin.com/dDCcATHm

Comment: @McMatt Did you check the response json?  it is not a valid json and I have double check your code, it just fine

Comment: @duongkhang that's the exact Json it responds with. What is wrong with it

Comment: @McMatt can you give me the api key or request url? I want to check the original responded json

Comment: @duongkhang "https://api.etsy.com/v2/shops/LifeAround2Angels/listings/active?api_key=" don't think I'll give api key, sorry

Comment: @McMatt Try json_decode($response_body,true);

Answer (score 0):

json_decode returning null can be possible if the data that has been passed as an argument is an invalid JSON or empty.
So make sure the response is in correct JSON format